# C++ Как сравнить два массива типа char?

Tags: c++, структуры, if, сравнение

Нужно ввести группу. Далее перебрать структура, найти запись с совпадающей группой и вывести её.

```
struct TZap{        
     char n_group[5];
     } Zap;
  char kodG[5];
  scanf("%s", &kodG);            // ввод группы для сравнения
  for (i=0; i < kol-1; i++) {     // Цикл перебора 
    if(mas_Z[i].n_group == kodG) { // Проверка на совпадение
      Out(mas_Z[i]);               // Передает в функцию запись для вывода 
    }
  }
```

Делал проверку, цикл  выполняется нужное количество раз, а вот условие вообще ни разу.

Почему я не могу сделать сравнение `mas_Z[i].n_group == kodS`?

**P.S.** Ввел небольшое недрзумение с `kodS`. Всё из-за моей невнимательности.
`kodS` заменил на `kodG`.

**UPDATE**

```
if(strncmp (mas_Z[i].n_group, kodG,1)==0)     
    puts ("TRUE"); 
else   
    puts ("FALSE");
```

Возвращает "TRUE". 
Если использовать `strcmp`:

```
strcmp(mas_Z[i].n_group, kodG);
```

Возвращает `0`. Это положительный результат проверки

Comment: `@AnT`, нашел у себя в коде опечатку. Исправил

Comment: Вы что ли с нуля *руками* сюда код набираете, вместо того, чтобы сделать copy-paste из реального кода?

Comment: @AnT, нет. Я написал вопрос и дальше пошел ставить эксперименты с кодом. Потом зашел сюда, увидел в одном месте `kodS` и заменил её на `kodG`, тем самом ввёл в заблуждение

Comment: Ну так может оно и правильно "всегда выводит FALSE". Нам отсюда не видно, что вы там вводите и что там у вас в структурах. Зачем вы делаете `cout << &mas_Z[i].n_group` и к чему это - не ясно. Зачем вы опять прилепили сюда этот `&`??? Что за манера всюду совать какой-то `&`?

Comment: @AnT, я не понимаю. Мне нужно сделать проверку значения структуры, так? Но, как это сделать правильно?

Comment: Вот так и сделать. Но судя по тому, что вы написали, у вас в структурах хранятся пустые строки. Поэтому ваши проверки и не работают. Это какая-то совершенно посторонняя проблема, с этим вопросом просто никак не связанная. Пока вы не заполните ваши структуры осмысленными данными, просто нечего проверять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Использование оператора `&` с форматом `%s` в `scanf` - почти всегда ошибка

   ```
   scanf("%s", &kodG);
   ```

   Что здесь делает этот `&`?

   Либо

   ```
   scanf("%s", kodG);
   ```

   либо (если угодно)

   ```
   scanf("%s", &kodG[0]);
   ```

   но ни в коему случае не то, что у вас. "На практике" ваш вариант может работать, но это не повод писать подобное.
2. Использование массива размером всего 5 для пользовательского ввода через `scanf("%s"` - это серьезная заявка на переполнение буфера со всеми вытекающими. Сделайте хотя бы

   ```
   scanf("%4s", kodG);
   ```
3. Сравнение С-строк в С++ делается так же как и в С: функцией `strcmp`.

   ```
   if (std::strcmp(mas_Z[i].n_group, kodG) == 0)
   ```
4. > Почему я не могу сделать сравнение `mas_Z[i].n_group == kodG`

   Кто вам такое сказал? Вы *можете* сделать такое сравнение. Только сравнивать оно будет не содержимое строк, а значения двух указателей (и они, разумеется, будут не равны). А уж что именно вы хотели сравнить - строки или указатели - это у вас надо спрашивать. Компилятор за вас додумывать не будет, он просто делает то, что вы ему сказали делать.

Comment: `&` убрал. Проблему не решило. Но и ошибки не было. `kodS` - это то, что я ввожу для сравнения

Comment: @Kyper: Ошибка, разумеется, была. Еще раз: использование оператора `&` с форматом `%s` - практически всегда ошибка.

Comment: Обновил текст вопроса

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужна [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp).

Но вообще, если это С++ (судя по тегу), то может иметь смысл избавиться от массивов символов и перейти на `std::string`.

---

Как в соседнем ответе заметили, в `scanf("%s", &kodG);` символ `&` - лишний. Хотя он здесь создает неопределенное поведение, на практике на работу программы он влиять не должен, по идее.

Comment: Я мог не верно выразится. В примере кода я показал, что и с чем я сравниваю. Надеюсь Вы понимаете тот код

Comment: @Kyper Что я понимаю, так это что `mas_Z[i].n_group == kodG` всегда вычисляется как `false`. Это два разных массива, соответственно адреса первых элементов (которые вы сравниваете) всегда будут разные. Если вам нужно сравнить символы в этих массивах - нужен `strcmp` или `strncmp`, или цикл по символам...

Comment: Обновил текст вопроса